# iOS 9: syncing problems with AVPlayer.masterClock

Tags: avplayer, avplayeritem, ios9.1

in my app I use `AVPlayerItem` to play sound and `AVPlayer` to play video. To sync both players I use the following code:

```
CMClockRef nc = CMTimebaseGetMasterClock(avPlayerItem.timebase);            
self.avPlayer.masterClock = nc;
```

On iOS 7 and iOS 8 it worked like a charm. But with iOS 9 I keep having problems. The playback starts but then always jumps back several seconds - so the playback is not fluent.

I would be grateful for every hint.

Thank you.

**Update**

It seems as if the `masterClock` is not the cause of the problem. I tried it without setting the `masterClock` and still had the same problem.

In another app I use an `AVAudioPlayer` for audio playback and an `AVPlayer` with `AVPlayerItem` for video playback and everything works fine.

In this app I have an `AVPlayer` with `AVPlayerItem` for both - audio and video playback and this seems to cause the problem. It worked fine with older iOS versions but not with iOS 9.

**Update**

I tested it with iOS 10 and the bug was gone. 
This problem only occurs under iOS 9.

Comment: Could you post your code example?